# How to secure Azure VPN using Azure AD authentication

Tags: vpn, azure, azure-activedirectory

I've set up an Azure VPN Gateway, and configured it to use Azure Active Directory as the authentication mechanism. I can assign AD users to the Azure VPN application, and control access via various policies with Conditional Access.

Users connect using the Azure VPN Client, which seems to be a requirement for using AAD as the authentication mechanism (the client application handles the Azure login flow to authenticate the user when connecting to the VPN).

This all works well, except for the fact that the Azure VPN client appears to cache the user credentials once they've signed in once. This still allows the user to connect to the VPN even if, for example, I've revoked their access to the Azure VPN application.

I'm trying to enforce a requirement that the user has to log in each time they connect to the VPN. That way, access controls and policies are evaluated each time they connect - e.g. requiring MFA each time they connect to the VPN. (Yes, I know this is going to be annoying for the end user - this is for a subset of administrative users with a ton of privileged access.)

Is this possible? How can I prove that we have the ability to revoke a user's access so they cannot connect to the VPN again without re-authenticating?

Comment: Maybe `Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken -ObjectId johndoe@contoso.com` could immediately block a user.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into your issue, and it seems that the CA policy does block it, but the vpn profile in the vpn client will have to be deleted. seems odd, almost like its caching the fact that they connected successfully and continures to let them do it. after removing profile it seems to not allow the connection.

Comment: once they have it they have it it seems, but it does restrict any randos and already existing users from accessing the VPN. in order to control already existing, it has to be at the account level IE block sign in.